# Is a compiled prepared statement stored within an object or in general?

Tags: java, jdbc

I know that, when used the first time, jdbc keeps somewhere the compiled prepared statement so that next time it will be accessed in a more efficient way.

Now, suppose I have this situation:

```
public class MyDao{
       public void doQuery(){
           try(PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(MY_STMT)){

            }
       }

 }
```

Both the following snippets will keep the compiled prepared statement in memory?

Snippet 1:

```
MyDao dao = new MyDao();
dao.doQuery(); //first one, expensive
dao.doQuery(); //second one, less expensive as it has been already compiled
```

Snippet 2:

```
MyDao dao = new MyDao();
dao.doQuery(); //first one, expensive
MyDao dao2 = new MyDao();
dao2.doQuery(); //will it be expensive or less expensive?
```

I am afraid that, by creating a new dao object, the jvm will see that prepared statement as a new one and so it will not compile it.

And, if it's not the case, is there any situation in which the jvm will "forget" the compiled statement and will compile it again?

Thanks

Comment: I'm quite certain that JDBC *itself* does not specify that compiled prepared statements be cached on the client (Java) side. Certainly some database engines will cache execution plans on the server side, and some ORMs (or similar) may attempt some client-side caching of *results*, but it seems rather unlikely that there would be any client-side caching of *compiled statements* (and any such attempt would depend heavily on the implementation of the JDBC driver in any case).

Comment: @GordThompson The JDBC specification does say something about pooled (cached) prepared statements in section 11.6 (JDBC 4.2), but whether drivers cache prepared statements is implementation specific. And even then, the pool would be tied to the connection.

Comment: Can JDBC still not just send parameterized queries without the need to store a prepared statement in the driver/client? With ADO.NET one just sends a query with binding parameters, and the database remembers the query by the query string, reusing the precompiled plan. This works both with SQL Server (procedure sp_executesql) and Oracle (internally with execute immediate). Does JDBC not have a similar way to just send queries, to be stored, remembered and reused by the database?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the clarification. When I was writing the comment I was perhaps a bit too focused on the notion of "compiled" and the implication that the JDBC driver might locally cache a version of the "compiled" query (or db-specific execution plan). No doubt that a JDBC driver could conceivably maintain the association between a client-side `PreparedStatement` object and a server-side "compiled query" (e.g., something like the result of `sp_prepare` for SQL Server), but that would depend on the driver implementation.

Comment: @ErikHart That is what the `PreparedStatement` is for, just like the `Command` object in ado.net. It is up to the driver implementation if they really prepare a statement server side or not. The only real difference with ado.net is that you can't assign a different statement to an instance of a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Keeping a Command or PreparedStatement object in the code is just what I want to avoid. I create a new Command whereever I need it, and when it's the same SQL, the database uses the previous execution plan. Just the difference between `sp_prepare` and `sp_executesql` procedures on SQL Server: first returns a handle to be executed instead of SQL string, the second just gets the SQL and remembers if the same SQL has been sent before.

Comment: @ErikHart As I said, it works the same in JDBC as in ADO.net, you don't have to keep it around, but in some cases (depending on driver implementation and other factors) it can have real performance benefits to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic scenario for prepared statement reuse is that your code keeps the `PreparedStatement` open and reuses that prepared statement. Your example code does not fit this criteria because you close the prepared statement. On the other hand trying to keep a prepared statement open for multiple method invocations is usually not a good plan because of potential concurrency problems (eg if multiple threads use the same DAO, you could be executing weird combinations of values from multiple threads, etc).

Some JDBC drivers have an (optional) cache (pool) of prepared statements internally for reuse, but that reuse will only happen if an attempt is made to prepare the same statement text again on the same physical connection. Check the documentation of your driver.

On a separate level, it is possible that the database system will cache the execution plan for a prepared statement, and it can (will) reuse that if the same statement text is prepared again (even for different connections).

Answer (score 0):

You're correct it will be compiled again.  PreparedStatements will only be reused if you actually use the statement itself multiple times (ie, you call `executeQuery` on it multiple times).

However, I wouldn't worry too much about the cost of compiling the statement.  If your query takes more than a few milliseconds, the cost of compiling will be insignificant.  The overhead of compiling statements only becomes apparent when doing 1000's of operations per second.

Answer (score 0):

Do a benchmark. It is the best way to get some certainty about the performance difference. It is not necessarily the case that the statement is always recompiled at server side. Depending on your RDBMS, it may cache the statements previously compiled. In order to maximize the cache hit probability, submit always exactly the same parameterized SQL text and do it over the same connection.